# Apply processor on several items instead of one in Spring btach

Tags: java, spring-batch

In one of my batch, i need to call a web-service to enrich some data from an item read in db, check some values and then write this enrich item into another table.
My web-service can support several requests in the same call in order to minimize the number of calls to the web-service. Actually my web-service call is defined as a processor:

```
<batch:tasklet task-executor="taskExecutor">
  <batch:chunk reader="bookingReader" processor="bookingEnrichWSProcessor"
    writer="bookingCompositeWriter" commit-interval="10" />
</batch:tasklet>
```

It seems that only the item writer can support writing several items in one call using property commit-interval in the step definition.

What i need is to read items ten by ten with the reader, and call the ws with the 10 items before wirting them again in another table.

Is it possible to do that in a processor class? or should i port this logic in a writer.

Thanks for our help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your reader, processor and writer: the reader must output an object.
This object could be a List < something>.

Then the processor is getting this List as a parameter and can call your WS with the items in the list.

Finally, the writer will also get a List of objects. You write them. DO not forget to remove the commit-interval : as you process only a single object (a List of 10 elements), you set commit-interval to 1 (if you want to write your 10 elements).